# Excel VBA Code Gives Error if Word Document is not already Open

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies if this is an obvious question but I've got a problem with some VBA code which is attempting to import some data from a word file into an Excel spreadsheet. There's some basic tables in the word documents which are fine but one of them is also in a text box. I can get the import to work in this case, but only if the word file is already open. I'm not sure why this is the case.

If it helps the error is: Run-time error, Automation error, Unspecified error.

```
    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc*),*.doc*", , _
         "Browse for file containing table to be imported")
         
   If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)
   
   Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)   'open Word file
   
   excelRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' find next blank row in excel spreadsheet based on column A
   
    With wdDoc
      
        TableNo = wdDoc.Tables.Count 'find total number of tables in the document
        
        'This is the line that triggers the error if the word document is not already open, there are 7 shapes in the document for reference.
        shpTableCount = .Shapes(4).TextFrame.TextRange.Tables.Count
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetOpenFilename` only provides a file name `GetObject` only picks the Word instance of that file if it is already open. If it is closed (means you get an error on `GetObject(wdFileName)` you need to open it with

```
Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(wdFileName)
```

So you can do

```
'check if it is already open
On Error Resume Next 'hide all error messages
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)
On Error Goto 0 're-enable error messages

'if it is not open, then open it
If wdDoc Is Nothing Then
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(wdFileName)
End If
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. So I tried replacing the original Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) line with this section and the get the same error, presumably becuase the Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) line means wdDoc is not nothing and therefore it doesn't go into the If statement? If I just use the Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(wdFileName) code it works - do I need to ensure I close the document at the end of the sub as well?

Comment: You always need to close your document if you want to open it with `Documents.Open`. If you don't close it, it will stay open.

Comment: Ah sorry I meant, at the end of the vba code, I was wondering if I needed to use something else having openined the document but a bit of research indicates I should still be fine with Set wdDoc = Nothing.

Comment: Yes but you should close the document with `wdDoc.Close` before you `Set wdDoc = Nothing`